# Как обрезать элементы массива до и после символов?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть массив $links, он заполнен такими ссылками:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.domen.com/images/750*200/50235.jpg)
    [1] => https://www.domen.com/images/750*200/3745.jpg)
    [2] => https://www.domen.com/images/750*200/945.jpg)
)
```

Нужно заполнить другой массив элементами, где будут храниться названия файлов из этих ссылок, т.е. 50335, 3745, 945 (без .jpg в конце и всего, что до)

Пробовал через preg_match, но выходит не совсем то, что нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярные выражения для этого вообще не нужны:

```
$result = array_map(
    function($v) { return pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_FILENAME); },
    $links
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ['https://www.domen.com/images/750*200/50235.jpg',
    'https://www.domen.com/images/750*200/3745.jpg',
    'https://www.domen.com/images/750*200/945.jpg'];

foreach ($arr as &$elem) {
    $elem = explode('/', $elem);
    $elem = str_replace('.jpg','',$elem[count($elem)-1]);
}

var_dump($arr);
```